# UIBarButtonItem image is stretching, even though the image used is the recommended 20 x 20 pts

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to customize my navigation bar, and have 2 bar button items that need to display icons. I've just created the bar button items in storyboard and set each one's image as the icon. The icons are both correctly sized pngs (20 x 20pt), however they are displaying much larger than they should be so they look stetched in both directions on the nav bar.

I'm doing everything in storyboard, except I had to add some code in the viewDidLoad method. I'm not sure if that effects anything, but here it is:

```
//Make the navigation bar transparent
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//Setup navigation bar with Avenir Next Regular font and white title color
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:17], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

I'm a coding newbie, and this is my first question here. I'd post in image to illustrate the problem but I need 10 reputation points to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the images in several resolutions for different devices. The easiest way to do this is to use the xcassets folder in Xcode and fill in all the templates: normal size, 2x, 3x.

If you don't want to use the xcassets you have to name the files yourself:

```
image.png
image@2x.png
image@3x.png
```

Xcode chooses the correct size automatically.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thankyou. I didn't even know about xcassets so will read up on them now!